# Glide crop image without image view

Tags: android, android-glide, android-wallpaper

Am trying to set wallaper in the backround with glide.It all works fine but the applied wallaper is of like the corners of the image.Since am ruuning it in job Service i cannot use a image view to scale the image.Is there any way to crop the image without it.Triied using centerCrop() on Glide but not working.

```
@Override
public void onComplete(Photo photo) {

    String photoUrl = photo.getUrls().getRegular();
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asBitmap().load(photoUrl)
        .apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop()).into(new
    SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource,
        @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
            WallpaperManager wallManager =
            WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                wallManager.clear();
                wallManager.setBitmap(resource);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: read `android.graphics.Canvas` API documentation

Comment: maybe the bitmap aka resource you have before applying to wallManager you can get the settings done in bitmap! i used this technique to reduce the size and of the image and video files like whatsapp or facebook does! i think that would work too in your USE CASE

Comment: its like i need the center of orginal bitmap to the phones display height and width

Answer (score 1):

You can use [custom transformations](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Transformations) to crop the bitmap at the callback method of [BitmapTransformation](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/load/resource/bitmap/BitmapTransformation.html).

And there are some very good references for [transformation examples](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations), it's very easy to use.

Here is my test code with kotlin:

```
val photoUrl = "imageurl"
    val target = object : SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(450, 450) {
        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(resource)
        }
    }

    GlideApp.with(this@MainActivity).asBitmap().load(photoUrl)
        .apply(bitmapTransform(RoundedCornersTransformation(38, 0, RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.ALL)))
        .into(target)
```